# How to connect two field in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, cascading-dropdown

I am trying to connect 2 field. example In particular list.

There are 2 column (Car and model).

**Values:**

```
Car --> Audi, BMW, Mercedes
Model --> Audi A3, Audi A5, BMW X3, BMW X5, Mercedes c250, Mercedes c300
```

lets say user select Audi in Car then in model list should only display  Audi A3, Audi A5 in list box.

Your advice will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to add a Cascading Dropdown listjust like Jammin4CO said. You can do it codeless way or use content editor and some codes to achieve this.

A tutorial with sample code which you only need to change a bit:
[Cascading of Lookup Dropdown Fields on SharePoint 2013 and Office 365](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/cascading-of-lookup-dropdown-fields-on-sharepoint-2013-and-o/)

[How to create Cascading Drop Down list in SharePoint Online/2016/2013/2010 - Using SP Services (JS )](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OcTI_UQ55TM)

If you can use infopath, here is an OOB way without need to write codes:
[Cascading Dropdown in SharePoint List using Infopath Forms](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/11/cascading-dropdown-using-infopath-forms-in-sharepoint-list.html)

[InfoPath 2013 Web Browser- Creating Cascading Dropdown Fields with no Code](https://manojssharepointblog.wordpress.com/2012/12/23/infopath-2013-web-browser-creating-cascading-dropdown-fields-with-no-code/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you've asked for, but could you use a [Managed Metadata field](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-managed-metadata-column-8fad9e35-a618-4400-b3c7-46f02785d27f) to achieve the same result? You could create a term set called "Cars", and then the first level of terms would be makes (e.g. Audi, BMW, etc.) and then nested in each would be various models (e.g. A3 under Audi, X3 under BMW, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is called Cascading Dropdowns.  There are several options for this, but none are OOTB.  You can look at JS or third party. Just google or search SE, there are several with answers, none accepted.